# Align div to left and text to right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've made a design and want to replicate it in html and css. So far I've been able to make this:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]
I tried doing a lot of positioning stuff and also flexbox but it would always end up looking kinda messy. If possible I would prefer the solution in flexbox.

**HTML**

```
<section class="featuresSection">
            <div class="featuresSection-inner">

                <!--Find Movies Feature-->
                <div class="featuresSectionItem">
                    <div class="featureIconBorder">
                        <img>
                    </div>

                    <h3>Find your favourite Marvel Movies</h3>
                    <h4>Search for information on all your<br>
                        favourite marvel movies, animations,<br>
                        series and shows</h4>
                </div>

                <!--Cast Feature-->
                <div class="featuresSectionItem">
                    <div class="featureIconBorder">
                        <img>
                    </div>

                    <h3>Know your cast</h3>
                    <h4>Learn about the amazing cast members<br>
                        who acted in each and every marvel<br>
                        showcase</h4>
                </div>

                <!--Interact Feature-->
                <div class="featuresSectionItem">
                    <div class="featureIconBorder">
                        <img>
                    </div>

                    <h3>Interact with other fans</h3>
                    <h4>Talk with and discuss with other<br>
                        super marvel movie fans</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Features Section*/
.featuresSection-inner{
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.featureIconBorder{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 4px solid #F92636;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.featuresSectionItem{
    color: #F92636;
    font-family: Lao UI;
}

.featuresSectionItem h4{
    color: #F9647D;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display: flex for your item wrapper with flex-direction: row.
Then wrap the h3 & h4 in another div.

```html
<section class="featuresSection">
  <div class="featuresSection-inner">

    <!--Find Movies Feature-->
    <div class="featuresSectionItem">
      <div class="featureIconBorder">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h3>Find your favourite Marvel Movies</h3>
        <h4>Search for information on all your<br>
          favourite marvel movies, animations,<br>
          series and shows</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--Cast Feature-->
    <div class="featuresSectionItem">
      <div class="featureIconBorder">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h3>Know your cast</h3>
        <h4>Learn about the amazing cast members<br>
          who acted in each and every marvel<br>
          showcase</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Interact Feature-->
    <div class="featuresSectionItem">
      <div class="featureIconBorder">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h3>Interact with other fans</h3>
        <h4>Talk with and discuss with other<br>
          super marvel movie fans</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
/*Features Section*/
.featuresSection-inner {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;

}

.featureIconBorder {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 4px solid #F92636;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.featuresSectionItem {
  color: #F92636;
  font-family: Lao UI;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.featuresSectionItem:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.featuresSectionItem h4 {
  color: #F9647D;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.text-wrapper {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q91udb8a/

Comment: `flex-direction: row;` is unneeded extra line since it is default.

Comment: @Arfeo very true, I changed it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You may add only one line to `.featuresSectionItem` -- `display: flex;` and add a wrapper for your `h3` and `h4`:

```css
/*Features Section*/
.featuresSection-inner{
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.featureIconBorder {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 4px solid #F92636;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.featuresSectionItem{
    display: flex;
    color: #F92636;
    font-family: Lao UI;
}

.featuresSectionItem h4{
    color: #F9647D;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<section class="featuresSection">
  <div class="featuresSection-inner">

    <!--Find Movies Feature-->
    <div class="featuresSectionItem">
      <div class="featureIconBorder">
        <img>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>Find your favourite Marvel Movies</h3>
        <h4>Search for information on all your<br>
          favourite marvel movies, animations,<br>
          series and shows</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with flexbox.

1. Make your main div align on column.

```css
.featuresSection-inner{
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

2. Then the section item div to align row wise.

```css
.featuresSectionItem{
    color: #F92636;
    font-family: Lao UI;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the result?

Comment: Not exactly. But if you happen to understand flex and what I'm trying to answer, you should be able to get the view with my answer as base.

Answer (score 0):

To have the result you expect just a simple display:flex can do the thing each of your rows should be in a container with the same class and then apply a display:flex on the containers 
I've test it with your code on codepen [link to the code](https://codepen.io/sherlockholmes2045/pen/Powmmjp?editors=1100)

```css
/*Features Section*/
.featuresSection-inner{
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  display:flex;
}

.featureIconBorder{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 4px solid #F92636;
    border-radius: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.featuresSectionItem{
    color: #F92636;
    font-family: Lao UI;
}

.featuresSectionItem h4{
    color: #F9647D;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.description{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="featuresSection">
            <div class="featuresSection-inner">
                <!--Find Movies Feature-->
                    <div class="featureIconBorder">
                        <img>
                    </div>
                  <div class="description">
                    <h3>Find your favourite Marvel Movies</h3>
                    <h4>Search for information on all your<br>
                        favourite marvel movies, animations,<br>
                        series and shows</h4>
                  </div>
             </div>

                <!--Cast Feature-->
                <div class="featuresSection-inner">
                    <div class="featureIconBorder">
                        <img>
                    </div>
                  <div class="description">
                    <h3>Know your cast</h3>
                    <h4>Learn about the amazing cast members<br>
                        who acted in each and every marvel<br>
                        showcase</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Interact Feature-->
                <div class="featuresSection-inner">
                    <div class="featureIconBorder">
                        <img>
                    </div>
                  <div class = "description">
                    <h3>Interact with other fans</h3>
                    <h4>Talk with and discuss with other<br>
                        super marvel movie fans</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```